# LexRank summarization algorithm

Tags: nlp, nltk, summary, summarization

I am working on an implementation of the `LexRank` ([link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_summarization#Unsupervised_approaches%3a_TextRank_and_LexRank)) algorithm for a project.

The thing I didn't understand about the algorithm is after I create the final matrix where the calculated tf-idf values are (after factoring their prestige). How do I create a summary?
Do I just take the top-k sentences? Do I remove one sentence, add it to the summary and start the process again without it? or something else?

Answer (score 2):

From the Wikipedia entry for `Automatic Summarisation`

> In both algorithms [LexRank & TextRank], the sentences are ranked by applying PageRank to the resulting graph. A summary is formed by combining the top ranking sentences, using a threshold or length cutoff to limit the size of the summary.